# Curving an image that starts as a rectangle (uploaded by user), preferably using Canvas or JS

Tags: canvas, curve

I'm trying to create a site that curves an image uploaded by a user, and then allows the user to save the new image. I'm having trouble figuring out how to curve the image as shown in the link below. I can create the curved shape as a solid color in Canvas, but not with an image.

http://i53.tinypic.com/2gule04.jpg

Answer (score 4):

I tried something like this.

[image]

I have a source image having width 300 and height 227. And I am going to bend this image 15 pixel down. So create a canvas with same width and height = imageWidth + 15 px. ie. 227+15 = 242.

**HTML:**

```
<img id="source" src="rhino.jpg">
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="242" ></canvas>
```

**Javascript**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementById('source');

var x1 = img.width / 2;
var x2 = img.width;
var y1 = 15; // curve depth
var y2 = 0;

var eb = (y2*x1*x1 - y1*x2*x2) / (x2*x1*x1 - x1*x2*x2);
var ea = (y1 - eb*x1) / (x1*x1);

// variable used for the loop
var currentYOffset;

for(var x = 0; x < img.width; x++) {

    // calculate the current offset
    currentYOffset = (ea * x * x) + eb * x;

    ctx.drawImage(img,x,0,1,img.height,x,currentYOffset,1,img.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do this. You might need to code the transformation yourself using the pixelwise API of Canvas. See http://beej.us/blog/2010/02/html5s-canvas-part-ii-pixel-manipulation/ .

Instead of pure pixel based solution you could try a mesh based one. Split up the source image to smaller chunks that map to the target shape. Then use texture mapping to fill in the details. See [Image manipulation and texture mapping using HTML5 Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774172/image-manipulation-and-texture-mapping-using-html5-canvas) for the mapping algo. You may find another algo [here](http://acko.net/blog/projective-texturing-with-canvas). You'll still need to figure out the mapping coordinates, though.