# How to draw rectangle by given coordinates with skew angle and rotation angle?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

[image]
the result didn't match the frame perfectly...
How can I draw a rect on the canvas stage by given 4 coordinates?

The given coordinates has a little skew angle, I failed to draw it with skew angle, Didn't know how to calculate skew angle with 4 coordinates
this is what I can get so far, I can draw it with rotation angle. What else have I missed? you can copy the html code and see the result..

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124127/skew-size-and-rotate-a-rectangle-to-fit-triangle-perfectly) tells how to calcute the skew angle with triangle, but how to use it in rect..

I'm high school student, my math is not so well, please forgive me ..:(

Thanks..

```js
var _width, _height;
var img = new Image();
var img2 = new Image(),
  img2Widht = 0,
  img2Height = 0;
img.src = "http://production.manboker.com/share/1.jpg";
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
img.onload = function() {
  canvas.width = _width = this.width;
  canvas.height = _height = this.height;
  img2.src = "http://production.manboker.com/share/2.png";
  img2.onload = function() {
    step1();
  }
}

var coor = {
  leftTop: ["92", "569"],
  rightTop: ["672", "569"],
  leftBottom: ["109", "1437"],
  rightBottom: ["723", "1437"]
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function step1() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, _width, _height);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(coor['leftTop'][0], coor['leftTop'][1]);
  ctx.rotate(radian(coor['leftTop'], coor['leftBottom']));
  img2Widht = distance(coor['leftTop'], coor['rightTop']);
  img2Height = distance(coor['leftTop'], coor['leftBottom']);
  ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, img2Widht, img2Height);
  ctx.restore();
}

function distance(a, b) {
  var x = b[0] - a[0],
    y = b[1] - a[1];
  return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

function radian(a, b) {
  return Math.atan2(a[0] - b[0], b[1] - a[1]);
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="position:absolute;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Either one of your school-mates or one of your other selves already  came here with [such a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500175/how-to-draw-image-by-given-coordinate-on-canvas#comment70210045_41500175). He was told that it is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372692/image-manipulation-add-image-with-corners-in-exact-positions) question. Yours also is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image Manipulation - add image with corners in exact positions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372692/image-manipulation-add-image-with-corners-in-exact-positions)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426887/how-to-skew-image-like-this)

Answer (score 0):

To correctly fit an flat image into a photograph of a frame in 3d, in general you not only need rotation and skewing (or more generaly affine transformations) but instead a projective transformation. Such a transformation is uniquely defined by the images of four points, as long as no three of these lie on a common line. [Finding the Transform matrix from 4 projected points (with Javascript)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) on Math SE and [Redraw image from 3d perspective to 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14244616/1468366) here on SO are answers where I describe how to do that.