# HTML5 canvas based Texture mapping optimization

Tags: javascript, graphics, html5-canvas

In question [Image manipulation and texture mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774172/image-manipulation-and-texture-mapping-using-html5-canvas)

The following piece of code achieves texture mapping using vanilla javascript on
a canvas..

```
         function textureMap(ctx, texture, pts) {
             var tris = [[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 0]]; // Split in two triangles
             for (var t=0; t<2; t++) {
                 var pp = tris[t];
                 var x0 = pts[pp[0]].x, x1 = pts[pp[1]].x, x2 = pts[pp[2]].x;
                 var y0 = pts[pp[0]].y, y1 = pts[pp[1]].y, y2 = pts[pp[2]].y;
                 var u0 = pts[pp[0]].u, u1 = pts[pp[1]].u, u2 = pts[pp[2]].u;
                 var v0 = pts[pp[0]].v, v1 = pts[pp[1]].v, v2 = pts[pp[2]].v;

                 // Set clipping area so that only pixels inside the triangle will
                 // be affected by the image drawing operation
                 ctx.save(); ctx.beginPath(); ctx.moveTo(x0, y0); ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
                 ctx.lineTo(x2, y2); ctx.closePath(); ctx.clip();

                 // Compute matrix transform
                 var delta = u0*v1 + v0*u2 + u1*v2 - v1*u2 - v0*u1 - u0*v2;
                 var delta_a = x0*v1 + v0*x2 + x1*v2 - v1*x2 - v0*x1 - x0*v2;
                 var delta_b = u0*x1 + x0*u2 + u1*x2 - x1*u2 - x0*u1 - u0*x2;
                 var delta_c = u0*v1*x2 + v0*x1*u2 + x0*u1*v2 - x0*v1*u2
                               - v0*u1*x2 - u0*x1*v2;
                 var delta_d = y0*v1 + v0*y2 + y1*v2 - v1*y2 - v0*y1 - y0*v2;
                 var delta_e = u0*y1 + y0*u2 + u1*y2 - y1*u2 - y0*u1 - u0*y2;
                 var delta_f = u0*v1*y2 + v0*y1*u2 + y0*u1*v2 - y0*v1*u2
                               - v0*u1*y2 - u0*y1*v2;

                 // Draw the transformed image
                 ctx.transform(delta_a/delta, delta_d/delta,
                               delta_b/delta, delta_e/delta,
                               delta_c/delta, delta_f/delta);
                 ctx.drawImage(texture, 0, 0);
                 ctx.restore();
             }
         }
```

The bottle neck here is the context saving and restoring (for the clipping region).

Any ideas how I can do away with the clipping and significantly improve the performance ?

I tried several things, however as there is no way to restore the clipping
region with javascript without rolling it inside a save/restore, I'm
stuck for ideas.

Comment: If it's the same image you are rendering many times with different clips, consider using a pattern. A pattern has its own transform `CanvasPattern.setTransform(DOMMatrix)`, set the pattern `ctx.fillStyle = myPattern;`,  set the patterns' transform, and rather than clip use fill `ctx.moveTo(x,y),... ctx.lineTo(xn, yn)` then `ctx.fill();`. This will save you needing to save and restore the context state. But only if you are using the same image as creating a pattern can be more expensive than restoring a clip.